# Dependent dropdown in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a market, submarket, store no. Columns, I want to use a drop-down to select the market submarket and store no. to display the details of the shop in Excel.
When I choose a market-only submarket belonging to that market should appear in the submarket drop-down, similarly after choosing the submarket-only, stores belonging to that submarket should appear in the store drop-down list
how do I do this?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Show examples of your data and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is the following, assuming I correctly understood what you want to achieve. Let's assume you have the following data in the range `A1:C11`:

| market | submarket | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | s1 | 1 |
| m1 | s1 | 2 |
| m1 | s2 | 3 |
| m1 | s2 | 4 |
| m1 | s3 | 5 |
| m1 | s4 | 6 |
| m2 | s1 | 1 |
| m2 | s2 | 2 |
| m2 | s3 | 3 |
| m2 | s3 | 4 |

Now, we need to create a helper table. To do this, copy the headers of your main table to, e.g., the range `E1:G1`. Next, add the following formulas to `E2`, `F2`, and `G2`, respectively:

```
=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$11)
=UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$11, $A$2:$A$11=$J$1))
=UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=$J$1) * ($B$2:$B$11=$J$2)))
```

This formulas are used to filter only the relevant observations, e.g., when you filter market "m1" that you get only the available submarkets etc. The output is a dynamic array that we use as input for the drop-down list. In that we, we only have always the relevant observations.

Now, we need to set up the drop-down list as follows using the dynamic arrays created with the formulas above: For the first list, e.g., in cell `J1` go to -> tab `Data` -> `Data Validation` -> `Allow: List` -> `Source: =$E$2#`. Now repeat this step in cells `J2` and `J4`, while changing the source to `=$F$2#` and `=$G$2#`, respectively. The `#` is needed to tell Excel that it should consider the entire array of the spilled array. In addition, you could specify in column `I` the respective aspect you want filter (see below).

In the end, you file should look as follows:

[image: Result]